# How to troubleshoot queue-triggered Azure Function (Python) will not trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I've had an Azure Function working for like 3+ years. I've made all sorts of changes over the years, no triggering issues. I just updated one line and republished using Azure Function Core Tools (the same method I've always used to publish to Azure).

For some reason, the queues are just sitting in the Queue Storage, but they are not triggering the Function.

**Done so far**:

0. Made one new change to the python code

```
#chunk = downloader.read(size=CHUNK_SIZE)
chunk = downloader.read(size=min(CHUNK_SIZE, end - offset + 1))
```

1. `func azure functionapp publish <my-function-app-name>`
2. The `Remote build succeeded!`
3. Uploaded a file to Blob Storage (where I have an EventGrid subscription setup)

   - This is the same thing that has worked for 3+ years
4. I verified that `App Settings` have not changed at all (notice, I didn't use the `--publish-local-settings` flag)
5. I restarted the Function App
6. Published 2x, deployment center shows all good

   - [image]
7. The function executed a couple times then quit

   - [image]
8. Here are the queue's just sitting in the Queue Storage, not triggering the Function

   - [image]
9. Can't figure out why the "Advanced Filters" are sometimes executing...

   - I can't really tell what is going on here...need a way to dig in to see what these values mean.
   - That last "event" didn't trigger the Function either...
   - [image]

I'm at a loss here. Does anyone have a tried and true method for troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Grrrr... was the `queueName` in `function.json`. I need a cleaner way to handle DEV/PROD environments. I had a `prod` suffix though I was publishing to `dev`.